# Is the Special Traffic Management Program (STMP) still in use?

Tags: air-traffic-control, faa, air-traffic-management

I'm doing some research on [STMP](https://www.fly.faa.gov/estmp/index.html).

- [this NBAA link](https://nbaa.org/aircraft-operations/airspace/atc-issues-procedures/ski-country-stmp/e-stmp-is-gone-but-winter-demand-at-colorado-airports-remains) say that STMP is gone.
- however, [this link](https://testfly.faa.gov/estmp/index.html) makes it look like STMP was in use for oshkosh 2021. the subdomain may indicate it wasn't used though so it's just not clear.

My question/s:

- is STMP dead?
- if so, does anyone know when and why it ended?

Answer (score 2):

i found some additional information about Oshkosh 2021. their [NOTAM (page 25)](https://www.eaa.org/-/media/Files/AirVenture/FlyingIn/NOTAM/2021/2021-06-28-EAA-AirVenture-Oshkosh-2021-NOTAM.ashx) specifies that IFR arrivals and departures must use e-STMP. so it is definitely still alive for certain airports when needed.

[image]